# save date field to oracle via sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I define my mapper like this:

```
col = Column(Date).
```

When I save data to oracle, I use datetime.datetime.now() as value for col, it raise

```
NotSupportedError: (NotSupportedError) Variable_TypeByValue(): unhandled data
type time.struct_time
```

I need to store only date information into this field, but I don't know how to do it. I'm also
curious about how to store datetime to a field.

The evn:python 2.7.3,  sqlalchemy0.8.0b2, cx_Oracle 5.1.2

Comment: `datetime.date.today()` is of type [`datetime.date`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects)

Comment: that sounds more like you're calling the `time.localtime()` function, which returns a `struct_time`.   `datetime.now()` returns a `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: I'm new to python and sqlalchemy, I don't know which object or which function to use

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue for different data type and find this solution it may help you as well.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/SdgEyyAPwvE

Example :
**Apache config**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testenv-test.my.fq.dn
    ServerAlias testenv-test

    WSGIDaemonProcess testenv user=michel threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/michel/testenv/wsgi/app.wsgi
    SetEnv MYAPP_PATH /var/www/michel/testenv/config

    <Directory /var/www/michel/testenv/wsgi>
        WSGIProcessGroup testenv
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/www/michel/testenv/logs/error.log
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/www/michel/testenv/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```